# How to use regex in postgres query to find all text after a match

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

```
id | url
---------
1  | "facebook.com/user?query=hello"
2  | "stackoverflow.com/question/?query=postgres"
3  | "facebook.com/videos?"
4  | "facebook.com/user?query="
```

So, this is not the best example, but essentially there is a field in the table I'm querying that is a URL and contains query inputs as well, I want to only select urls that have something after `query=`

so I would want to get rows 1 and 2.

It would be even cooler if I could also capture what might follow after? (`hello`, `postgres`)

Thank you for any insights or help

Answer (score 0):

You can readily select the rows using:

```
where url like '%query=_%'
```

You can get what comes after in several ways.  Here is an easy way:

```
select (case when url like '%query=_%'
             then substr(url, position('query=' in url) + 6)
        end) as querystring
from pageviews;
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm trying to execute this (I appended from <table_name>) and it's saying that it cannot find table named `url`? Do you know why that might be?

Also `like '%query=%` will still return the rows with nothing after, such as row 4 in my example.

Comment: `where url like '%query=_%'` according to _"select urls that have something after `query=`"_

Comment: @loonyuni . . . `url` is a column name.  I don't know what the table name is.

Comment: so lets say that `pageviews` is the name of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is more index-friendly solution:

```
drop table if exists foo.t;
create table foo.t (x bigserial, url varchar);
insert into foo.t(url) values
  ('facebook.com/user?query=hello'),
  ('stackoverflow.com/question/?query1=postgres'),
  ('facebook.com/videos?'),
  ('facebook.com/user?query=');
insert into foo.t(url) select url from foo.t, generate_series(1,100000);
create index iturl on foo.t(position('?query=' in url), length(url));
explain analyze select * from foo.t where position('?query=' in url) > 0 and length(url) > position('?query=' in url) + 7;
```

And result is:

```
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=3736.79..12211.16 rows=67005 width=37) (actual time=62.072..407.323 rows=100001 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ("position"((url)::text, '?query='::text) > 0)
   Filter: (length((url)::text) > ("position"((url)::text, '?query='::text) + 7))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 100001
   Heap Blocks: exact=3449
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on iturl  (cost=0.00..3720.04 rows=201015 width=0) (actual time=60.473..60.473 rows=200002 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("position"((url)::text, '?query='::text) > 0)
 Planning time: 0.512 ms
 Execution time: 423.587 ms
(9 rows)
```

Note that I changed your initial data to make index selectable (1/4 hits).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wild card `%` with a `like` clause.

```sql
SELECT * FROM person WHERE email like '%gmail.com%';
```

This will get all the emails with `gmail.com` in `email` column from `person` table.

**The below part may be out of context for this question but if someone wants to use regex**

`~` character can be used to match a regex e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM person WHERE email ~ '[A-Z]';
```

This will list all the rows where `email` column contains uppercase letters